# Getting server name the client know behind a reverse proxy within a Java EE web application

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, redirect, proxy

For my Java EE web application I have a problem. I need to redirect a page A to another page B, using Spring controller I write:

Page A is for my browser (in http):

```
      http://MYPUBLICSERVERNAME/MYCONTEXT/A.do :
```

In A which is a Spring controller has the following code for redirection:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/A.do")
public String searchProfiles(){
....
return "redirect:/B.html";
}
```

It works perfectly in http.
so I go to B :

```
  http://MYPUBLICSERVERNAME/MYCONTEXT/B.html
```

The problem comes with HTTPS because with HTTPS a reverse proxy intercept the request :

This proxy is on the same machine and I get :

impossible to connect because when i go to :

```
httpS://MYPUBLICSERVERNAME/MYCONTEXT/A.do
```

i expected to be redirected to :

```
httpS://MYPUBLICSERVERNAME/MYCONTEXT/B.html
```

Instead the browser is redirected to

```
 http://localhost/MYCONTEXT/B.html
```

I understand that for the server the client is the reverse proxy not of course the browser.

So my question is : how can the servlet get the original server name i mean the server name indicated in the web browser (MYPUBLICSERVERNAME) and the protocol (HTTPS if HTTPS).

The workaround i think is using a cookie feeded by the browser, because the browser only know MYPUBLICSERVERNAME but maybe more elegant solution exist ?

Of course if I know a spring function that can magically redirect with expected protocol and server name it's ok too but i didn't find it.

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the redirect with the whole path and protocol

```
   return "redirect:https://MYPUBLICSERVERNAME/MYCONTEXT/B.html"
```

I am not sure if you can use refferer header in request (does proxy change the refferer ?)

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

Comment: referrer is a good solution, i get the right protocol and server name from the server even with proxy. thank you !

Comment: just have in mind that referrer is "client" based, so it has no to be fully reliable.

Comment: yes i understand that. If the referer  is modified by the client the consequence is that the client could not reach the page, our clients are not supposed to do that ! (and if they do that there is no security problem because we check of course user grant server side)